# Curl code to PHP with properties

Tags: php, curl

I have the following Curl code, which I used the curl to PHP converter to convert to PHP code

```
curl https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v1/list/dqQnNW/members \
  -X POST \
  -d api_key=API_KEY \
  -d email=george.washington@example.com \
  -d properties='{ "$first_name" : "George", "Birthday" : "02/22/1732" }' \
  -d confirm_optin=true
```

The code I got was

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v1/list/dqQnNW/members");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "api_key=API_KEY&email=george.washington@example.com&properties='{&confirm_optin=true");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

However this doesn't seem right because of the "properties" line which doesn't get translated into the PHP code.

How do I incorporate the "properties" line with a $first_name variable into my PHP code?

Comment: -d =data, properties is just a string, and its in your php code

Comment: How do I incorporate that into the code? I have zero knowledge of Curl code, unfortunately.

Comment: its already there `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "api_key=API_KEY&email=george.washington@example.com&properties='{&confirm_optin=true")`

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually define the content-type headers, as PHP will detect the appropriate [content-type based on an array or URL encoded `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#refsect1-function.curl-setopt-notes) Other than that you could simplify it by using an array of values and `http_build_query` https://3v4l.org/jJcsa

Comment: @smith wait, how does that code see that the first name is George then? If George isn't anywhere inside the CURLPOT_POSTFIELDS and neither is $first_name ?

Comment: @fyrye not sure what you mean by this as I'm a total noob. Any chance you could write some sample code that could help me out?

Comment: Did, https://3v4l.org/jJcsa the link at the end of the comment

Comment: @fyrye got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah it's definitely not correct, the converter screwed up the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS line.

try

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'api_key=API_KEY&email=george.washington@example.com&properties={ "$first_name" : "George", "Birthday" : "02/22/1732" }&confirm_optin=true');
```

instead. and if you can be arsed, send a bugreport to the author of the converter, this is definitely a bug.

and protip, in php, you might wanna use the http_build_query function instead for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-encoding, and json_encode for json encodig, eg

```
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query ( array (
        'api_key' => 'API_KEY',
        'email' => 'george.washington@example.com',
        'properties' => json_encode ( array (
                '$first_name' => 'George',
                'Birthday' => '02/22/1732' 
        ) ),
        'confirm_option' => true 

) ) );
```

also note, are you sure you're using this api correctly in your curl example? it's mixing `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-encoding with json-encoding, that's unusual. a weird design choice if correct. i'd double-check if that's the correct behavior with the docs if i were you.